# Selling on Chrome Web Store with Google Wallet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, payment, chrome-web-store

I tried publishing Google App Script on Chrome Web Store and sell but it seems that generating JWT (JSON Web Token) is currently available in server side languages like Ruby, PHP, Java and Python.

Anyone successfully built something using GAS and sell on Chrome Web Store and selling using Google Payment API?

Comment: Just an idea ... use GAE to do the JWT bit of the code. Then forward/proxy to the GAS code.

Comment: Thanks.  But how do I communicate between GAS and GAE through secured channel?